# Adding rows and columns with buttons equally in a table

Tags: javascript

can someone please give me little help here I am stuck with this I have no more ideas, My problem is that in this table I am able to add a row and a column but when I add for example a row and there are 5 rows now, but when I try and add a column it does not know how to match the cells number as much as there are rows and it looks like this:

[image]

```
<table class="optionsForm" id="table_id" style="width:100%">
            <tbody>
              <tr >
                <th> 
                  </th>  @for($c = 1; $c<=4; $c++)
                    <th id="column{{ $c}}">   
                      <input type="text" name="columns[{{ $c }}]"  
                      class="form-control" placeholder="Column {{ $c }} "> 
                    </th>
                    @endfor
                  </tr>  
                  @for($r = 1; $r<=4; $r++)
                    <tr id="option{{ $r }}">
                      <td>
                        <input type="text" name="rows[{{ $r}}]"   class="form-control" placeholder="Row {{ $r }} ">
                        <div id="column{{ $r }}">
                          <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="1" class="col1">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="2" class="col2">
                            <input type="hidden" name="row_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="{{ $r  }}" class="col2">
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]"  value="3" class="col3">
                            <input type="hidden" name="row_nr[{{ $r  }}]"  value="{{ $r  }}" class="col3">
                          </td> 
                          <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="4" class="col4">
                            <input type="hidden" name="row_nr[{{ $r  }}]"  value="{{ $r  }}" class="col4">
                          </td></div>
                          <input type="hidden" value="[0]" class="row_col_nr{{ $r  }}">
                        </tr>
                        @endfor
                        <tr> 
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>                          <button style="margin:8px;" type="button" value="{{$c}}" class="btn btn-flat btn-default btn-sm"
                         id="delete_column" title="@lang('buttons.remove_option')">
                         <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true">
                         </i>
                       </button>

                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary btn-sm" id="add_column" title="@lang('buttons.add_new_option')">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                      </button>
```

and here I have the javascript code:

```
var i = 4;
  var r = 4;
  var p = 1;


  $(document).ready(function () {
     var totalRowCount = $("#table_id tr").length;
   var rowCount = $("#table_id td").closest("tr").length; 

    $('#add_option').click(function () {
      rowCount++;
      i++;
      r++;
      $('.optionsForm').append('<tr id="option' + rowCount + '"><td><input type="text" name="rows['+ r +']" class="form-control" placeholder="Row ' + rowCount +' "><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ rowCount +']"  value="1" class="col1" ></td><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ rowCount +']" value="2" class="col1" ></td><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ rowCount +']"   value="3" class="col1" ></td><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ rowCount+']"value="4" class="col1" ></td></tr>');
      $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
      increaseArea: '20%' // optional
    });
    });
    $(document).on('click', 'button[id=delete_option]', function () {
      console.log('test');
      if (i > 1) {
        var removeValue = $(this).val();
        console.log(removeValue);
        $('#option' + removeValue).remove();
        --i;
      }
    }
    );
  }
  );
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var i = 1;
 var p = 4;
   var totalColCount = $("#table_id th").length;
            var col_count = totalColCount - 1;   
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add_column").click(function (){
    p++;
    col_count++;
    var trow;   
    var columnContent = ['<input type="text" name="options'+ i +'" value="{{ old('options. + p +') }}"  class="form-control" placeholder="Column ' + col_count +' ">', '<input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ i +']"  value="1" class="col1" >', '<input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ i +']" value="2" class="col1" >', '<input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ i +']" value="3" class="col1" >', '<input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ i +']" value="4" class="col1" >'];

    for(var i=0; i<columnContent.length; i++){
      r++;
      if(i==0){
        $('.optionsForm ').find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').append('<th>' + columnContent[i] + '</th>');
        $('.optionsForm').append('<tr id="option' + r + '"><td><input type="text" name="rows['+ r +']" class="form-control" placeholder="Row ' + r +' "><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ r +']"  value="1" class="col1" ></td><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ r +']" value="2" class="col1" ></td><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ r +']"   value="3" class="col1" ></td><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ r+']"value="4" class="col1" ></td><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ r+']"value="5" class="col1" ></td></tr>');

      } else {
        $('.optionsForm ').find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').append('<td>' + columnContent[i] + '</td>');
      }
    }

    $('input').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
          increaseArea: '20%' // optional
        });
  });
```